# PHP validating query

Tags: php, validation, query-string

I have this query here that I add on to the end of my URL `status=1&time=1030&start=Toronto&end=Boston`

I am looking for away to validate these to see if status, time (and time is 4 characters only), start and end

I tried the following:

```
if(!isset($_GET['status'])){
   //error message and die
}

if(!isset($_GET['time']) || $_GET['time'] < 4){
   //error message and die
}

if(!isset($_GET['start'])){
   //error message and die
}

if(!isset($_GET['end'])){
   //error message and die
}
```

But it always display the first error message and dies, even thought its in the query.How do I fix this?

Comment: You must be making some mistake, because it should work as intended. checking for typo...

Comment: This seems obvious but you did put a `?` before adding `status=1&time=1030&start=Toronto&end=Boston` like this: `www.mysite.com?status=1&time=1030&start=Toronto&end=Boston`.

Comment: $_GET['time'] < 4, you mean strlen($_GET['time']) < 4?

Comment: You could use `&&` operator to put everything together. Consult the PHP manual on the subject http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: ^--- `$a || $b Or TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.` - `$a && $b And TRUE if both $a and $b are TRUE.`, as quoted from the PHP manual. Your problem may be because once **one** (`||`) of the conditions is true, it may die on that instance. I think you're looking of **both** or all are true (`&&`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your page is http://stackoverflow.com.

Make sure to add your query after "?" so your URL should be
    like this :
    http://stackoverflow.com?status=1&time=1030&start=Toronto&end=Boston

The other possibility is you use $_POST method in your page. Try to change $_GET to $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using isset()

`if(!$_GET['status'] || strlen($_GET['time'] != 4 || !$_GET['start'] || !$_GET['end'])
{
    // error handling
}`